# How to convert nominatim file to osm file pbf?

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, nominatim, osm.pbf

I have a backup file from postgresql of nominatim. Now I want to convert that backup file into OSM's PBF file, is it possible? If yes give me some suggestions on the conversion . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Nominatim doesn't store raw OSM data in a database. During import it removes all information that isn't necessary for geocoding and transforms data in such a way that typical geocoding tasks can run efficiently. It is not possible to convert the results back into the original OSM PBF.